# Constructing numpy arrary based on dimension and known values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a grib2 data which is of 0.5 deg resolution. Its lat ranges from `-90` to `90` and lon ranges from `0` to `359.5`. I would like to create a numpy array out of this known values to plot it on Basemap. I used wgrib program to see the lon values and it goes like this:-

```
[0.0, 0.5 ... 359.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0 ... 359.5 ....]
```

When I looked at the values carefully, the range of values `0.0 to 359.5` is created repeatedly many times. Its dimension is `(259920,)`. How do I create this 1D arry out of above known values. I tried `np.linspace`, but it created evenly spaced values which is not expected.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How about `np.tile(np.arange(0,360,0.5),361)`?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not just reading the data out of the GRIB2 file and into an array? ([There's a module for that.](https://jswhit.github.io/pygrib/docs/index.html))

Comment: Yes. The pygrib module is little slow. I would like to work with wgrib2.

Comment: @Divakar, Your code produces two dimensional arrary. However, the original data is of one dimension.

Comment: @sundar_ima What version of NumPy are you on?

Comment: That was my bad. It was 1D only. However, When I tried to convert in to 2D arrary for basemap plotting, it produces `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 259200 into shape (361,720)`

Comment: Feed it : `np.tile(np.arange(0,360,0.5),361).reshape(361,720)`?

Comment: No this one `np.tile(np.arange(-90,90,0.5),720).reshape(361,720)`